# How does this order-by-order inversion of series done?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the paper: DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevE.99.022411, on page 3, it is given that

> $$
> \psi^{\prime}(s)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{2 \mathcal{B}_{2 m}}{(2 m) !} \frac{\phi^{(2 m)}(s)}{\ell_{0}^{2 m-1}}
> $$
> wherein $\mathcal{B}_{0}=1, \mathcal{B}_{1}=-\frac{1}{2}, \ldots$ are the Bernoulli numbers (of the first kind).... While we are not aware of any explicit expression for the coefficients of the inverted series, it is straightforward to **invert the series order-by-order** by substituting back and forth, and thus obtain
> $$\phi(s)=\frac{\psi^{\prime}(s)}{2 \ell_{0}}-\frac{\psi^{\prime \prime \prime}(s)}{24 \ell_{0}^{3}}+\frac{\psi^{(\mathrm{v})}(s)}{240 \ell_{0}^{5}}+\cdots$$

How is this order-by-order inversion of series done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose it is given that
$$ \psi^{\prime}(s)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{2 B_{2 m}}{(2 m) !} \frac{\phi^{(2 m)}(s)}{\ell_{0}^{2 m-1}} = 2\ell_0 \phi(s) + \frac{\phi''(s)}{6\ell_0} -\frac{\phi^{(4)}(x)}{360\ell_0^3} + \dots $$
where $\,B_{2m}\,$ the the Bernoulli numbers and $\,\ell_0\,$
does not depend on $\,s.\,$ To find $\,\phi(s)\,$ in
terms of $\,\psi\,$ and its derivatives a natural Ansatz is
$$ \phi(s) = a_1 \frac{\psi'(s)}{1!\,\ell_0} +
 a_3 \frac{\psi^{(3)}(s)}{3!\,\ell_0^3} + 
a_5 \frac{\psi^{(5)}(s)}{5!\,\ell_0^5} + \dots $$
for some rational coefficients $\,a_n.\,$
Use the first equation to find the odd derivatives
of $\,\psi(s)\,$ and substitute them in the Ansatz
and compare with $\,\phi(s).\,$ This gives the
linear equations
$$ 0 \!=\! -\!1\!+\!2a_1 \!=\! a_1\!+\!2a_3 \!=\! 
a_1\!-\!10a_3\!-\!6a_5 \!=\! a_1\!-\!7a_3\!+\!21a_5\!+\!6a_7
 =\dots.$$
Solve the linear equations one by one to get
$$ a_1 = \frac12,\,a_3 = -\frac14,\,a_5 = \frac36,\,
a_7 = -\frac{17}8,\, a_9 = \frac{155}{10},\,\dots. $$
The coefficients are explicitly given by
$$ a_n = \frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1}(2^{n+2}-2).$$
Note that $\,-(n+1)a_n\,$ is [OEIS sequence A001469](https://oeis.org/A001469) "Genocchi numbers (of the first kind)".

Comment: how did you obtain those linear relations between the coefficient $a_i$s?

Comment: @Our Thanks for asking. I added some more explanation to my answer.